# How to add types for object with varying number of key/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

My API returns an object with a key/value pair for each particular entity in a database table. If it were a recipe app, for example, the key would be the recipe ID and the value would be the recipe name. Therefore, the number of key/value pairs is unknown at compile time.

The client is written in Typescript and requires safe typings. How can I add types to an object when I don't know how many key/value pairs the object will contain when retrieved from backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic key/value objects are pretty straightforward to describe with a type.  For example:

```
interface Item {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean 
}
```

Comment: would this apply to every key/value pair on the object? I was under the impression this would only apply the type to the first key/value pair

Comment: No the type 'Item' describes object with arbitrary string keys whose values can only be a string, number, or boolean.  so {foo: null} would not pass the typechecker but {foo: 1, bar: '2'} would.